# 例文ですか。入っている辞書の数はこれより少なくてもかまいませんか

Tags: grammar

> 例文ですか。入っている辞書の数はこれより少なくてもかまいませんか。([source: line 15](https://www.docdroid.net/dEbqqGI/img-20170816-0001-new.pdf))

I have a strong feeling that lots of information in this sentence has to be extrapolated from the context. First, a translation as literal as possible:

> Examples? Concerning the Number of entered dictionaries, is few from this okay?

Here, my main issue already surfaces: 入っている辞書の数
With the meanings provided by jisho, I can’t make a meaningful expression out of this. If they are talking about the number of entries of dictionaries into whatever-thing, then I don’t know what this whatever-thing is.
If they are talking about “entries inside the dictionary”, then I dare not making the assumption all on my own that 入っている辞書 means exactly this.

Next is これより. I think it relates to the topic of this sentence, but since I can’t interpret the topic in the first place, I can’t be sure. However, if one of my interpretations of the topic was correct, “from this” still lacks a reference value. What is “the number of dictionary entries” or “entered dictionaries”? No “number” was mentioned before.

Answer (score 3):

So, the item ミラー is trying to purchase is a 電子辞書 - an electronic dictionary.
First he is offered product that allows the user to write characters on the screen to search for it, as well as jumping between dictionaries for the same entry, such as between the Japanese dictionary to a Japanese to English dictionary, etc. However, ミラー says that it doesn't provide a lot of example sentences, and asks the teller if there's any dictionary that provides a lot of example sentences, to which the teller responds:
"Let's see, more examples...... would it be alright if the product offers a smaller variety of dictionaries (such as the Japanese dictionary and the J->E dictionary in the previous product)?"